# How many parameters does the varargs facility permit in java?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I am interested in knowing how many parameters you can pass using the varargs facility in Java.

Is there a JVM or Memory limit?
As far as I can understand it varargs is implemented as an array so the limit is determined by the amount of memory. Is this correct?

Comment: When your design is good, you shouldn't worry about that, if you're worried about passing 10+ arguments, you should reconsider your design.

Comment: AFIK it is internally handled as an Array so the same rules should been applyed. However I think it makes no sense to use a method with more then 10 arguments.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Um... I wouldn't exactly call it a design flaw to construct a list of more than ten things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Try to allocate the memory which is greater than your Pergemn memory, that throws `OutOfMemory`.

note that there is no speciality about array or varargs here. You can freely use your memory below the memory you allocated.

I hope this is just for learning and not using those many in your application.

Comment: I'm just interested in limits. I usually use not more than 3-5 parameters. So basically it has a memory limit. I see.

Answer (score 3):

Varargs is syntactic sugar for an on-the-fly array that is just large enough to fit the elements coded.

The limit then would be the size of an array, which is 2<sup>31</sup> (ie large).

Considering the size is specified by the actual number of parameters coded, you will never have to worry about it.

---

A quick test confirms that the usual method parameter count of 255 does not apply to individual varargs elements.

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit limit for the number of variable arity arguments. However the method size is limited. It should not exceed **65535 bytecodes**.

When `javac` compiles a call to a variable arity method, it creates and fills the array using the pattern like:

```
+0: dup
+1: bipush <index> (or sipush if index > 127)
+3: iconst_0
+4: iastore
+5: dup
    ...
```

So, filling one array element takes 5 or 6 bytecodes.
This means you can practically call a method with a little more than **10K arguments**.